# React - Fill select dropdown with data from API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, javascript-objects, fetch-api

I want to fill my `select>option`s with datas fetched from api. Everything works fine, I can see my datas on `console` or another `div`, but in `option` tags they seem like `Object object`. How can I fix it ? Here are my codes:

```
    state = {
        loading: true,
        city: null,
    }
    async componentDidMount(){
        const url = ...;
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                ...
            }
        })
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({city: data.results[0], loading: false})
    }

...

<select>
  <option>Select city</option>
  <option>
    {this.state.loading || !this.state.city ? (<p>Loading...</p>) : 
    (<p>{ this.state.city.name }</p>)}
  </option>
</select>
```

p.s: I should display not only 0-th datas properties, but all of datas' properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<option>
    {this.state.loading || !this.state.city ? (<p>Loading...</p>) : 
    (<p>{ this.state.city.name }</p>)}
  </option>
```

The above code will not work as

or any other tag cannot reside inside option tag
the p tag get outside the option tag and not visible
[image]

Comment: So ? What to do ?

Comment: remove p tag directly implement the text 
<options> {this.state.city.name}</options>

Comment: Now it returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null`

Comment: Edit the above code so there will be clarity
`<options> {this.state.city ? this.state.city.name:'Loading'}</options>`
Please vote